# android soap web service - not retrieving output

Tags: android, web-services, soap, asmx

```
private final String zipCodenameSpace ="http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
private final String zipURL="http://www.webserviceX.net/uszip.asmx";
private final String zipSoapAction ="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByCity";
private final String zipMethodName="GetInfoByCity";



SoapObject request = new SoapObject(zipCodenameSpace, zipMethodName);
         PropertyInfo cityInfo = new PropertyInfo();
         cityInfo.setName("USCity");
         cityInfo.setValue(city);
        // cityInfo.setType(String.class);
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         request.addProperty(cityInfo);
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

         envelope.dotNet = true;

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(zipURL);

         try {
             androidHttpTransport.call(zipSoapAction, envelope);

         //    Object response =(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            Log.d("This is an element", response.toString());
          //   tv.setText(response.toString());

           //  return response.toString();

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
                      }
```

Showing null exception. Error is occurring at soapObject  response.

I tried to use soap primitive but not working. Please help me where the problem is

Given Webservice returns xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
cityInfo.setValue(city);
```

Where are you fetching this "city" value in your code? I think thats the problem. For testing you can set it as string directly here.like "NewYork".